# mysql commandline execution of query with its output having the rows affected

Tags: mysql, command-line, resultset

When I execute a particular query from mysql prompt,for example

```
mysql>select version();
```

the output is as below along with the number of rows and time taken for query execution

```
+-------------+
|  version()  |
+-------------+
|  5.5.35     |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need to execute mysql query from the commandline using "-e" option,i.e.when i execute

> mysql -u xxx -p*** -e'select version()'

the following output gets displayed

```
+-------------+
|  version()  |
+-------------+
|  5.5.35     |
+-------------+
```

I need to show the output along with the rows and execution time, when query is executed from the commandline.I know that

> select row_count();

and

> select found_rows();

can be used to get the number of rows affected and number of rows in the table respectively based on the last query executed.

Is there any mysql options or any other way to get the desired output as in the case of former without adding additional commands or queries.